# Print an array of number in a textView, but in ordered columns

Tags: ios, textview

i wrote a code to print a bidimensional matrix in a textView

```
NSString *stringaTmp;
    NSMutableString *mutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    for(int i = 0; i < square;++i ){
        for(int j = 0; j < square;++j ){
            stringaTmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", myMatrix[i][j]];
            [mutableString appendString:stringaTmp] ;
            [mutableString appendString:@" "] ;
        }
        [mutableString appendString:@"\n"] ;
    }
    matrixTable.text = mutableString;
```

I would like to know if there was a way to print the matrix so the columns are aligned.
This is an example:

```
1  2  3
34 11 2
1  3  11
```

Otherwise, if I print with the method above, all of the columns are unaligned:

```
1 2 3
34 11 2
1 3 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to add a tab character between the numbers instead of a space.

Change this line

```
    [mutableString appendString:@" "] ;
```

to

```
    [mutableString appendString:@"\t"] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this and I'm not in front of a Mac right now, but possibly you can use these string formatting techniques:

http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~trnka/CISC105-04F/making_columns.html

You can try doing something like this to test it:
`stringaTmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-5d%-5d%-5d",34,134,4];`

No matter how you do this make sure to use a fixed width font in your UITextView.